# How to change keyboard layout on XFCE?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xfce

I'd like to change and see the keyboard layout using XFCE. Is there any simple way to do that? I had one when using gnome, but currently I want to use XFCE.

Comment: did you solved it ?

Comment: no, I just run each time I start XFCE: `setxkbmap 'pl(intl)'`

Comment: did you need write password for it?

Comment: no, no password, I just write it in console and it just works